# How change Microclimate push repository?

Tags: ibm-cloud-private, microclimate

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://github.com/ibm-cloud-architecture/refarch-cloudnative-bluecompute-microclimate

Using the ICP hosted trial environment that can be reserved here: https://www.ibm.com/cloud/garage/tutorials/ibm-cloud-private-trial/ibm-cloud-private-hosted-trial

That environment uses the hostname "secure.bluedemos.com" instead of the default "mycluster.icp". The tutorial I'm following imports a GitHub project into Microclimate, which automatically starts building an image for the application. However, I'm receiving this error:

The push refers to repository [mycluster.icp:8500/default/mc-bluecatalog-d5b489a261653078ec31fa2af0ae7405529784]
Get https://mycluster.icp:8500/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for secure.bluedemos.com, secure-emea.bluedemos.com, secure-aus.bluedemos.com, secure-apac.bluedemos.com, not mycluster.icp
Error: 1, could not push application image mycluster.icp:8500/default/mc-bluecatalog-d5b489a261653078ec31fa2af0ae7405529784

This is expected, since the environment is configured to use secure.bluedemos.com instead of mycluster.icp. How can I change the push command to push the image using secure.bluedemos.com? Is this a Microclimate configuration or ICP? This makes me wonder how to deal with these configurations when not using the default "mycluster.icp" on custom ICP installations on customers' environments, for example.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In the step where you do the `helm install` for the Microclimate chart, you need to override the registry location e.g. add a `--set jenkins.Pipeline.Registry.Url=secure.bluedemos.com:8500`. You can see the full set of overrideable values in the chart [here](https://github.com/IBM/charts/blob/master/stable/ibm-microclimate/values.yaml).

Comment: Thanks David, I end up uninstalling and installing again Microclimate with the correct registry location